# Java JComboBox Drop Down event

Tags: java, events, jcombobox

Is it possible to determine when a user clicks on a JComboBox to drop down the list of items in it?  I just want to capture this event, not when an item is selected from the list.

Many thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use JComboxBox#addPopupMenuListener(PopupMenuListener listener)

Answer (score 10):

You can use a PopupMenuListener to determine when the drop down is about to open. Add it using the: addPopupMenuListener-Method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/PopupMenuListener.html

Use this method

```
  void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with method `JComboBox.addPopupMenuListener(PopupMenuListener l)`.